# "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA" error when trying to use my function. Can anyone help me debug this?

Tags: r

I currently have function "get_col_mean" that is supposed to take in a dataframe and column name existing in the dataframe, and take the mean of the values in the respective column:

```
get_col_mean <- function(data_frame, column_name){
  return(mean(data_frame$column_name, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

However, when I try to do so with my dataframe "life_exp" and column name "X1900":

```
test2 <- get_col_mean(life_exp, "X1900")
test3 <- get_col_mean(life_exp, X1900)
#(not sure which one of these is supposed to work; one of them should work, but as of now, neither work)
```

I get an error:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(data_frame$column_name, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

HOWEVER, when I type the line out that I have as my return line inside of my function in an isolated line as such:

```
test1 <- mean(life_exp$X1900, na.rm = TRUE)
```

It works perfectly, and I receive the mean of the values in the column.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my function? I'm trying to attach a picture of what the life_exp data.frame looks like but I can't find any way to do so (first time using this website). In an attempt to explain it, all of the rows represent a country and all of the columns represent a year (X1900 being the year 1900). Row "Afghanistan" + column "X1900" would give a number representing the life expectancy of a person in Afghanistan in the year 1900.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to pass a string, use `[[` instead of `$`

```
get_col_mean <- function(data_frame, column_name){
          mean(data_frame[[column_name]], na.rm = TRUE)
      }
get_col_mean(life_exp, "X1900")
```

using a reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
get_col_mean(mtcars, 'mpg')
#[1] 18.72
```

For the second case, i.e. passing unquoted column name, we can use `deparse(substitute`

```
get_col_mean <- function(data_frame, column_name){
          mean(data_frame[[deparse(substitute(column_name))]], na.rm = TRUE)


      }

get_col_mean(life_exp, X1900)
```

Similarly with the same reproducible example

```
get_col_mean(mtcars, mpg)
#[1] 18.72
```

---

The issue is that `$` will look for the literal value pass i.e. 'column_name' instead of the value passed in it

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me and now I am trying to use the following code `col_means <- lapply(life_exp, get_col_mean, paste("X", 1800:2100))` to create a list of life expectancy means for every year. However, when I try to run this line of code, it gives me error `Error in data_frame[[column_name]] : attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex` what am I doing wrong? Or do you think I should post this as a separate question/post?

Comment: @ZinekromC Here, you need `lapply(paste("X", 1800:2100), function(x) get_col_mean(life_exp, x))`. But, this is more easier with `colMeans(life_exp[paste("X", 1800:2100)])`